# Retrive data with LEFT OUTER JOIN when Condition false otherwise INNER JOIN

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In a proc I need to retrieve data based on a condition.

If that condition is false I need to use LEFT OUTER JOIN but if that condition is true I need to use INNER JOIN.

This is what I tried.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFooBarData]    
@UDT VarcharUDT readonly
AS BEGIN    

DECLARE @IsUDTNull BIT
SELECT @IsUDTNull = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @UDT),0)

SELECT [Foo], 
       [Bar]
  FROM [dbo].[FooBar] FB
  LEFT OUTER JOIN @UDT T ON @IsUDTNull = 0 OR FB.Foo LIKE '%' + T.Item + '%'
END
```

I call proc like this

```
DECLARE @sa VarcharUDT

INSERT INTO @sa (Item)
SELECT 'XS0995537155'

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetFooBarData]
        @UDT = @sa

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

This does not works as expected and returns all data even when UDT contains value.

UDT

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[VarcharUDT] AS TABLE(
    [Item] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Item] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this in one statement, then use a `LEFT JOIN` and check the condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT [Foo], [Bar]
FROM [dbo].[FooBar] FB LEFT OUTER JOIN
      @UDT T 
      ON FB.Foo LIKE '%' + T.Item + '%'
WHERE (@UseLeftJoin = 1) OR (T.Item IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Plus one. Used this to fetch data.